# Getting data from one listview in the commandarguments of a nested listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview  (the outer list) where each item in the list is composed of a button and a nested listview (the inner list). the inner list is actually a radiobuttonlist, but for this question I don't think that matters. The point is they're nested.

When rendered, it looks something like this:

[image]

I would like to program the following two events:

1) When a user clicks on a button (NOT a radiobutton) of the outer listview (the buttons look like an icon of a document), the command argument should be composed of the index of the item of the clicked button AND the index of the selected radio button of that item. For example, if i click on the button of item 2, the arguments should be 1 (idex of item 2) and 2 (index of footer in that radiobuttonlist)

2) When a user clicks on a radio button, the exact same event should happen.

I'm having trouble with getting the radio button index in the command argument of a buttonclick, and I'm also having trouble getting the item index in case of a radiobuttonclick. How can the outer listview get data from the inner and vica versa?

Here's my asp.net code:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" 
    ID="TemplateTypeListView"
        ItemType="Invenso.CRM.XperiDo.Web.Pages.XperiDoTemplate.TemplateTypeItem"
        OnItemDataBound="TemplateTypeListview_OnItemDataBound"
        OnIemCommand="TemplateTypeListview_OnItemCommand">

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="TemplateTypePanel" CssClass="templateTypePanel" >

                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="TemplateTypeButton" CommandArgument=" ???? " />

            <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="templateTypeSubPanel">
                            <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="TemplateTypeSubtypeRadioButtonList" CommandArgument=" ???? " />
                    </asp:Panel> 

            </asp:Panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```